# What does DISPLAY=:0.0 actually mean?

Tags: xorg

What does the `:0.0` actually mean? I know that `:0` is the first X server that is started on a local machine, `:1` the second, etc. But what is that `.0` part after `:0`? Do other combinations exist? (e.g. `:0.0-something`)

Background: I'm trying to improve the initscript of [bumblebee](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned) which currently assumes that `:0` is the active display. That is not the case if I switch users. So I wanted to validate the `$DISPLAY` variable before passing it to `vglclient`.

Comment: FWIW, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Nomenclature helped me understand some of these terms. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1210332/266309) also has useful info.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The format of the display variable is `[host]:<display>[.screen]`.

`host` refers to a network host name, and if absent means to connect to the local machine via a unix domain socket.

Each host can have multiple displays, and each display can have multiple screens. Screens aren't used much anymore, with xinerama and now xrandr combining multiple screens into a single logical screen.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the right manual page too, `Xserver(1)` referred to the `DISPLAY NAMES` section of `X(7)`. Refer to that manual page for details.

Comment: And how would I get a list of available displays for a certain host? Ideally within an ssh session where i'm logged in at the host from a client PC.

Comment: @con-f-use That is a new question; you should create a new question rather than a comment.

Comment: The display part is also used on X over SSH. Every new SSH connection with X forwarding enabled is assigned a different display, because these screens correspond internally to a TCP port number offset, e.g. `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` will cause the client to direct graphical output to host `localhost` port 6010. This is required for SSH X forwarding, because if you have multiple connections to the same computer, your program must send different outputs to different ports so that the SSH server can forward the X output to the proper destination.

Comment: what port should be open if all the ports are block outbound from the server.

Comment: @Raza: The TCP port numbers to open are 6000 + display_number. For display host:0.0 that is port 6000. For display host:10.0 that is port 6010. Note that SSH X11 forwarding is done over port 22 and not X11 ports.

Comment: On my mac, `DISPLAY=:0 xterm` works, but `DISPLAY=localhost:0 xterm` does not work. How come? What's the default unix domain socket?

Comment: @Claudiu: DISPLAY=:0 will use a unix domain socket, DISPLAY=localhost:0 will use a internet domain socket (IP). It is likely your X server is not listening on a TCP/IP end point. I don't know the default unix domain socket.