# Is it possible to choose which X display a program instance should run on?

Tags: x11

If there are multiple X Windows running on a system, is it possible get a program to run on a particular window? How would you identify the Window and get the program to run there?

I'm assuming that I have whatever permissions are necessary to run such a program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does DISPLAY=:0.0 actually mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-does-display-0-0-actually-mean)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

X programs know which X session they're supposed to talk to by looking at the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

First you'll need to find out what `DISPLAY` is set to in the X session where you want your program to run. Do this by issuing the command `echo $DISPLAY` inside an X-terminal in that X session. Typically get something like `:0.0` is outputted.

Lets say you want to start the excellent program `xclock` program in your X session where `DISPLAY` is `:0.0`, but you want to do this at the console. You then press Alt-Ctrl-F1 to shift to that console, and then type:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock   # variables set w/ a command are local to that command
```

Then you go back to X by pressing Alt-Ctrl-F7 or Alt-Ctrl-F8 (or maybe some other F key, depending on your Linux flavor) and watch the new pretty wallclock you have there.

In fact you could've executed the above command *in any shell* on that same machine (via SSH, in any X session, on any console etc.) – the fact that you specified `DISPLAY=:0.0` before the command means that the `xclock` window will always pop up in the same X session.

In fact – apart from the fact that X programs look at it – there is nothing special about the `DISPLAY` variable. Normally when you're starting programs from an X terminal they start in the right place because `DISPLAY` has already been set for you.

Instead of using the above command, you can also split it into two by first setting `DISPLAY`, and then running `xclock`. In this case the `DISPLAY` setting will persist until you close that shell, and all subsequent X programs started from there will open in the same X session as `xclock`.

```
                      # variables set w/o a command are local to the shell,
export DISPLAY=:0.0   # unless exported
xclock
```

Comment: Note that the last bit won't work unless you export the shell variable to the environment first though.

Comment: I think `DISPLAY` will be set to export by default, since it is imported by the shell (it works in both `zsh` and `dash` for me without using `export`). But, yes, if you can't get the two line version to work, try replacing `DISPLAY=:0.0` with `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the X client programs use the `DISPLAY` environment variable to know which X server display to connect to. Some programs also accept a command-line parameter (`-display` or something similar) which can be used to override the `DISPLAY` environment variable.