# Can not run Spyder from conda env: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 error

Tags: installer-anaconda, spyder

When in conda environment I run spyder in my local machine (opensuse leap 15), I get the following error:

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyQXcbConnection: Could not connect to
>   display :0 Aborted (core dumped)

Reinstalling the env and/or spyder does not help, neither this thread ["Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" when trying to run program remotely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely)

It used to work untill today. Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue on a newly upgraded Leap15.1 OpenSuse installation, each time I launched a python3 qt5 app I got "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key".

The solution for me was to include all local connections in my Xauthority file like so:

```
user@pc:~> xhost +local:
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
non-network local connections being added to access control list
```

You get the error... but also the notice about adding non-network local connections.
Next time you run the test command... no error:

```
user@pc:~> xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
LOCAL:
```

From then on I could run my python3 qt5 app without getting the error.