# xhost: unable to open display "desktop:0"

Tags: python, display, qt, xhost

UPDATE 1: I am not using SSH. I am using a local machine.

UPDATE 2: I restarted the X and notice that the Xauthority file that I am exporting to is actually being updated:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart display-manager
$ ls /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority*
-rwx------ 1 mona mona 96 Jan 25 16:07 /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
```

Also, after I restarted the X, the other two Xauthority files, namely `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-c` and `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-l`, are gone as can be seen below:

```
$ fd Xauthority /
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
```

and I can call xauth after reboot:

```
$ xauth
Using authority file /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
xauth>
```

Following ["Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" when trying to run program remotely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely) I tried:

```
[9080:9072 0:2035] 02:14:50 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/vision/integration
$ export DISPLAY=desktop:0
18838/31772MB(vision)
```

and then:

```
$ xhost +local: 
xhost:  unable to open display "desktop:0"
```

how could I fix this problem?

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Another similar example:

```
$ xclock
Error: Can't open display: desktop:0
```

More details:

```
$ xclock
Error: Can't open display: desktop:0
27296/31772MB
[3266:3258 3:2008] 02:54:16 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ export DISPLAY=":0.0"
26016/31772MB
[3266:3258 3:2009] 02:57:24 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0.0
$ export DISPLAY=":0"
26238/31772MB
[3266:3258 3:2011] 02:57:40 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0
$ xhost +mona
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxhost:  unable to open display ":0"
$ firefox
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
 
 
$ xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0
25694/31772MB
[3266:3258 3:2026] 03:04:35 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ export DISPLAY=desktop:0
25694/31772MB
[3266:3258 3:2027] 03:04:49 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ xclock
Error: Can't open display: desktop:0
```

Also, I am having weird characters in Xauthority file:

```
$  xrandr | nc termbin.com 9999
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open display :0
21618/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2002] 03:49:16 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ fd Xauthority /
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-c
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-l
22048/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2003] 03:51:26 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-c
22048/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2004] 03:51:49 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority-l
22081/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2005] 03:51:58 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
gokuMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1R��9��s{�H��H�l��gokuMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1R��9��s{�H��H�l22081/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2006] 03:52:03 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
```

Also, setting it to the found Xauthority file didn't solve the problem:

```
$ export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
22022/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2010] 03:54:31 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0
```

I am uid 1000:

```
uid=1000(mona) gid=1000(mona) groups=1000(mona),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

I also have these about `xauth`:

$ xauth info
Authority file:       /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
File new:             no
File locked:          no
Number of entries:    2
Changes honored:      yes
Changes made:         no
Current input:        (argv):1
21740/31772MB
[11979:11971 0:2016] 05:26:34 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ xauth list
goku/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  SECRET_KEY
#ffff#676f6b75#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  SECRET_KEY

[image]

Comment: Notice that in the Q&A you link to the `desktop` in `desktop:0` is a placeholder for actual hostname of the machine. Does `ping desktop` work? But you better present your case from the start -- that Q&A you link to may be a dead end, with a problem completely different from yours.

Comment: no `$ ping desktop
ping: desktop: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: my problem is stuck at whatever x program I run with this error `Error: Can't open display: desktop:0`

Comment: Where are you trying to start that program from? Have you connected with ssh to another machine, as in the Q&A you link to?

Comment: I am not using SSH. I am running everything in a local machine ( a laptop).

Comment: @Quasímodo please check the screenshot I have uploaded to the end of this post.

Comment: Try setting `export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` (BTW that's a binary, not a text file -- the junk characters are OK).

Comment: @user414777 $ export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
22022/31772MB
[9136:3258 0:2010] 03:54:31 Mon Jan 25 [mona@goku:pts/2 +1] ~
$ xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0

Comment: @Quasímodo this is not my realm. Could you please provide a bit more step-by-step solution including the commands for doing so or link me with something that does so?

Comment: You can usually do that from the button in the top right corner and then clicking on your username > Log Out. But I suspect that something else's broken. Eg. with your terminal emulator.

Comment: in the 3rd paragraph of code, I can't disentangle the code from prompts and other stuff. Post code without prompts, to make it readable.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor please forget about the code. I cannot even run `xclock` command.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I followed your suggestion and removed the $ so it automatically is recognized as Python. However, please let's focus on getting xclock fixed.

Comment: If you should forget about your code, then why is it in the question?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
the code was an example that produces the problem, however, the problem is much bigger and is also produced by else thing. Please have a look at my initial post that was dealing with the code. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310286/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it thank you

Comment: If it is confusing me then it is distracting me form answering the question, as evident by this comment thread.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for your feedback. Removed the code and the error altogether to focus on the most pressing issue. The code and error are here https://pastebin.com/raw/hZtxBRTt

Answer (score 0):

```
$  export DISPLAY=:1.0
```

worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Yes I was just staring to wonder, if you had 2 X sessions running: I just noticed he screen shot of a perfectly functional X session, with you messing with stuff, and said "I wonder if you are trying to control another session?"