# Unable to launch applications from Terminal in XRDP session

Tags: rhel, xorg, remote-desktop, xrdp, alma-linux

I currently have an `AlmaLinux 9.3` machine with remote accessing using `xrdp`. I have noticed that if I try to launch a program via in a Terminal Window like `$ sudo gedit` I get the following error message:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gedit:21479): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:21:04.745: cannot open display: :10.0
```

However, if I execute the same command without `sudo` I get a gedit window appear. Or if I instead `su` to the `root` user account then execute the command `$ gedit` it works.

I would like to learn more about this error message and if there is anything I can do to rectify it. I have already looked around to see if others have experience this and I did find the following question asked: ["Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" when trying to run program remotely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely)

However, I have not tried them due to being unsure what they actually do to the system.

Additional info about my system listed below:

- xrdp session uses `Xorg`
- Desktop Environment: `xfce`
- `Microsoft Remote Desktop` used to access Linux Machine
- Login greeter: `lightDM`

`sshd_config` settings:

- `X11Forwarding yes`
- `X11DisplayOffset yes`
- `X11UseLocalhost yes`

I hope this information helps and thank you in advance.

Comment: What do commands `echo $DISPLAY` and `sudo echo $DISPLAY` return? Well, for the second one, you already wrote it is `:10.0`.

Comment: Hello @nobody, running both the commands you mentioned gave me: `:11.0` as the output. Does this info help at all?

Comment: Well, the question is, why do you get error report about display :10.0 if both commands say that :11.0 is used for displaying X11 applications.

Comment: You're absolutely right @nobody, I was surprised by the output showing `:11.0` instead of `:10.0`. Maybe that's the issue, the program is being sent to the wrong display ?