# What is the difference between **pts** and **tty** and **:0**?

Tags: tty, pty, who

Please help me to distinguish pts from gui mode generated from tty.

## booting to `multi-user.target`

I did this:

1. `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
2. reboot
3. login with regular user debian8
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f2</kbd> and login with regular user debian8 too.
5. run `startx` to switch into gui
6. run `tty` and `who`, which said:

   ```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/0
   $ who
   debian8  tty1         2017-01-09 20:22
   debian8  tty2         2017-01-09 20:23
   ```

Why is the output of `who` not this instead?

```
who
debian8  tty1         2017-01-09 20:22
debian8  :0         2017-01-09 20:23
```

I have run `startx` to enter into gui mode, and `tty` said `pts/0`.  So why does `who` output `tty2` not `:0`?

## My confusion after the explanation by Kusalananda

[image]

When `tty` is run, we get `/dev/pts/0`.  But look at the above.  In the TTY column of the output of `w` the row for `startx` says `tty2`.  Why6 is not `:0`?

What is the difference between `/dev/pts/0` and `tty` ?

The `tty2` output when I start X with `xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt2 -auth /tmp/serverauth.451rqHm1NC` — is it a pts or not?  It outputs

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

This says that the tty here is a pts, I think.

## booting to `graphical.target`

I did this:

1. `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`
2. reboot
3. login with regular user debian8
4. run `tty`, yielding

   ```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/0
   ```
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f2</kbd> and login with regular user debian8 too.
6. run `tty`, yielding

   ```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/1
   ```
7. run `w`

[image]

There are two guis.  They can be switched between with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f2</kbd>.

Running the command `tty`, both terminals say `/dev/pts/0` or `/dev/pts/1`.  But look at the output of `w` above.  Why does the terminal column for `/usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE` say `:0`? And why does the terminal column for `xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :1 vt2 -auth /tmp/serverauth.k7JPJJEAHJ` say `tty2`?

What is the difference between **pts** and **tty** and **:0**?

Comment: Well, you didn't login on `:0`, right?

Comment: yes not directly login on :0. .

Comment: reboot into text mode ,then switch to tty2 ,and input to startx ,to enter gui mode

Comment: Can you rewrite the question, using sentences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do as **booting to graphical.target** way.

```
ps -el |grep -v ?
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0   683     1  0  80   0 -  4867 -      tty1     00:00:00 agetty
4 S     0   901   686  1  80   0 - 63109 -      tty7     00:00:10 Xorg
0 S  1000  2390  2388  0  80   0 -  7368 -      pts/0    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  2465  2390  0  80   0 -  3935 -      pts/0    00:00:00 ps
0 S  1000  2466  2390  0  80   0 -  4446 -      pts/0    00:00:00 grep
```

1.tty7 and tty1-tty6
it is a kind of virtual terminal such as tty1-tty6.
proof1:in the output info  **ps -el |grep -v ?**,in the third line----**tty7**.
Proof2:man chvt
chvt - change foreground virtual terminal.
You can switch between tty1-tty7 with `sudo chvt n` (n's range from 1 until 7.)
tty7,belong to tty family,is a knind of vertual terminal ,and is in a gui mode,differing from tty1-tty6 which are in text mode.

2.pts
pts means pesudo tty slave which is used with the pseudo terminal master. 
To get the pts structure of telnet session from web page

[Description of a telnet session](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html)

in Figure 4: Description of a telnet session.

[image]

When bash (ps,grep) run on Xorg in my example,the pts structure is smoething like the below graph(enlightened by R.Koula,author of Description of a telnet session)

[image]

The controlling terminal for bash(ps,grep) is pts/0.

3.**:0**

```
w
 09:36:09 up 24 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.25, 0.29
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
debian8  :0       :0               09:12   ?xdm?   5:13   0.13s /usr/bin/lxsess

ps -lC lxsession
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  1585  1574  0  80   0 - 91715 -      ?        00:00:00 lxsession
```

From **ps -lC lxsession** it is obvious that lxsession is a daemon which has no controlling terminal,so **w** can't yield info such as ttynumber(from 1 till 7) or pts/number.
**w** yield :0 ,meaning **local:display #0** ,to describe the fact on the hardware side,Xorg runing at **local:display #0**.

Answer (score 11):

> What is the difference between `pts` and `tty` and `:0`?

- `pts` = "**p**seudo **t**erminal **s**lave": login device when connecting through the network or a console (e.g. ssh).
- `tty` = "**t**ele**ty**pe": serial or console connections (text mode)
- `:0`  = "local:display #**0**": X11 server, used for graphical login (e.g. gdm)

Answer (score 9):

The `who` utility by default displays information relating to the login.  If you logged in an `tty2`, then `who` will say so.

Use the `w` command to show information about the users currently logged into the machine and on what terminal they are doing what on.

Update:  "[What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)" describes some differences between a TTY and a PTY. `:0` is [the particular host display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-does-display-0-0-actually-mean) that you are connected to.