# pts abbreviation and old Unix words

Tags: terminal, tty, console, pts

I remember `tty` was the abbreviation of **TeleTYpe**. 
Now I don't know what `pts` (`/dev/pts`) stands for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \*\*pts\*\* and \*\*tty\*\* and \*\*:0\*\*?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335992/what-is-the-difference-between-pts-and-tty-and-0) - see also [`man pts`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/pts.4.html)